# svg/.ai file made with brushes, inverting stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, brush

I've created an svg in Illustrator using a rope brush which worked well but I want to invert the black and white which isn't working. It was done with a brush where stroke was black but fill wasn't used (it was black too but it doesn't use fill at all)

this is currently what I have
[image]

When I select the object and switch the stroke to white, it changes the black lines here to white, but I can't fill the rope gaps that are currently white. I literally just want to ingvert these colors completely.

What's the best way I can do this?

Comment: You need to alter the brush artwork. Not the strokes the brushes are applied to. Or expand the brush strokes so they are actual objects, then alter the objects. You may want to rewrite this question asking how to do those, if you are unfamiliar. As it is, it's kind of an [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) problem... you may be unaware of the actual problem.

Comment: There may not be a fill color to the rope, it may be transparent aside from the black lines in the image you provided. With the stroke set to black or white, did you try just creating an additional rectangle with a fill of any color, and putting it behind your rope? That might get you part way to what you need. Otherwise, as @Scott mentioned, you'd need to edit the brush itself to have a fill, or expand the stroke to paths and edit from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Edit the brush dragging it to from the Brush Panel to the artboard
- Select it and ungroup it
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Win to activate the **Shape Builder Tool** and click the areas where the brush must be black
- Select the new shapes and create a new pattern brush dragging them to the Brush Panel
- Apply the new brush to the path

[image]